# Can Functional Globals be used to share data between VIs running on different targets?

Tags: scope, labview

The [LabVIEW wiki](http://labviewwiki.org/Functional_global_variable) page on Functional Global Variables (FGV) states that

> The primary use of Functional Globals is to provide data sharing across an entire project, both horizontally and vertically.

In the past, I have successfully used FGVs to share data among VIs running *on the same target*.

In my current project, which involves multiple targets (namely, a host PC and a cRIO), I now want to pass configuration data between a Host VI and an RT VI, and I thought an FGV would come in handy for that.

However, it doesn't seem to work: I write to the FGV on the Host VI alright; but when I read data from the FGV in the RT VI, I only get default values, as if nothing had ever been written to the shift registers.

Before you suggest it: yes, I have checked the VI properties of my FGV; its execution is set, as it should be, to *non-reentrant*.

Can Functional Global Variables be used to share data between VIs running on different targets? Or is an FGV's scope limited to the target it runs on?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any answers to those questions in the LabVIEW online help, or on any LabVIEW discussion board...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional Global Variables only work within a single context.  Contexts only exist on one target (e.g. My Computer, a Compact RIO, RT device, etc).

FGVs are really just a neat way to create a shared value in a program using a feature of shift registers -- if you don't initialize the shift register on the diagram then it will be initialized with whatever value it hat last.  A VI that is running on two targets is not the same VI -- it's two copies of it.  So you have two copies of your FGV, which is why the data you want to share isn't being shared.

To communicate between two targets, I suggest you check out [shared variables](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4679/en/), [TCP](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2710/en/), or [network streams](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/12267/en/).  There are a lot of other options, but those are my favorite and easiest to set up in difference scenarios.